# How can I make a windows app in C# that for example automatically follows someone on Twitter when I open it up?

Tags: c#

If I were to follow USA Today on Twitter with a JavaScript code I could go to their page and paste this simple code in the console:

```
follow();
function follow(){
var button = document.getElementsByClassName("EdgeButton EdgeButton--secondary EdgeButton--medium button-text follow-text")[0];
button.click();
}
```

How can I trigger this code on a specific URL in C# (only after the page loaded)?

So what I'm trying to ask is how can I trigger a button in C# remotely, without actually visiting the page?

So it could be a simple console application too where I simply

```
string jsCode = "follow();
function follow(){
var button = document.getElementsByClassName("EdgeButton EdgeButton--secondary EdgeButton--medium button-text follow-text")[0];
button.click();
}";
string url = "https://twitter.com/";
List<string> pagesToFollow = new List<string>();
pagesToFollow.Add("USATODAY");
pagesToFollow.Add("RT_America");
pagesToFollow.Add("Reuters");
foreach (var s in pagesToFollow) whateverMethodGoesHere(url + s, jsCode);
```

This is pretty much what the app would look like but I have no idea how to execute a JavaScript code remotely and I yet to find a solution to the problem that the code should wait until the page is loaded.

Comment: Would it not be far simpeler to use a .Net client for twitter? See https://dev.twitter.com/resources/twitter-libraries for your options.

Comment: Thanks, that's pretty cool but actually Twitter was just an example, I'm asking this as a general question, like how could I trigger such a specific code on any site in C#?

Comment: `how to execute a JavaScript code remotely` You are on the wrong track. JS code runs in **your** browser.

Comment: Well, if you drop the requirement to not visit the page you might be able to use a webbrowser component (in winforms/wpf) that visits the page and you might get the html content from the page and work from there. Never tried it myself, so I do not know if it will work.

Comment: @PeterBons yea, exactly, I was thinking about something like that too if nothing else could work

Answer (score 0):

Considering it a general question as you request, a general answer would be something like this:

1. Use a proxy, like Fiddler, and study the HTTP requests done while performing the task you want to emulate. Then, replay the requests from your program.
2. Embed a headless browser like Chromium and control it from your code.
3. Use Selenium. There is a binding package in NuGet.
4. ... and many more, I suppose. This question is really open to speculation.